# Multiple datepickers not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the code to add a date picker. Working fine. but when I try adding more than one pickers (div). Only the first picker works, Can anyone explain me what is wrong. I need to add sixteen datepickers (inputs) in my timetable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
      <input type="text"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>


    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
      <input type="text"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm',
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: true   // enables the 12-hour format time picker

      });
    </script>

  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: You are using same id `#datetimepicker`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `id` by `class`, because id should be unique in same document :

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
```

Should be :

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
```

Hope this helps.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
      <input type="text"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>


    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
      <input type="text"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.date').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm',
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: true   // enables the 12-hour format time picker

      });
    </script>

  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: using it. I even lost the working first input date time picker

Comment: yeah I get it working with class instead of id. Thank you